# Allow skype calls from Angular App (using meanjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can not get rid of a small issue affecting my app functionality to enable to call a phone number using skype, what I have so far is this:

**HTML**:

```
<a ng-href="skype:{{user.phone}}?call" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">{{user.phone}}</a>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
(function() {
  angular.module('core').config(coreConfig);

  coreConfig.$inject = ['$compileProvider'];

  function coreConfig($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|skype):/);
  }
})();
```

The result is always the same, when I hover the element to start a call the browser show this: `unsafe:skype:012345678?call` and do not allow me to call the number...

I added the config part browsing other questions related to similar issues but it doesn't solve my issue.

**EDIT**:
I'm using [meanjs.org](http://meanjs.org)

**EDIT 2**:
Please do not copy/paste my question code as your answer... I know that it work on a normal Angular application. The problem is that I can not let it work using [meanjs.org](http://meanjs.org) app. Thanks.

**EDIT 3**:
I just found that: if I use the skype link in the main root `/` or in a child root like: `/list` it work fine without adding the `unsafe` prefix. In a dynamic root like: `/list/1234` it doesn't work anymore. I don't know if it could help.

Comment: you need to add white list in  `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist`

Comment: It is not what I did in config?

Comment: ok then try this `$compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|skype):/);` see this http://plnkr.co/edit/o2qiaLGOIO2tt07dQBC9?p=preview

Comment: As far as I knon `urlSanitizationWhitelist` is deprecated but I did a try and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "bug" was caused by an old version of `ngFileUpload` that overwrite my configuration as reported [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1014).

Upgrading the version of `ngFileUpload` solved my issue.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add URL protocols to Angular's whitelist using a regular expression. Only `http`, `https`, `ftp` and `mailto` are enabled by default. Angular will prefix a non-whitelisted URL with `unsafe:` when using a protocol such as `chrome-extension:`.

A good place to whitelist the `chrome-extension:` protocol would be in your module's config block:

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
        // Angular before v1.2 uses $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(...)
    }
]);
```

The same procedure also applies when you need to use protocols such as `file:` and `tel:`.

Please see the AngularJS [$compileProvider API documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compileProvider) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, as you can see from my question I already did it and the `unsafe` prefix is still there... I triple checked the app and there is nothing that can overwrite what I wrote... it just doesn't allow me to use it.

Comment: Have you added  |blob:chrome-extension: to the end?

Comment: Default imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist Angular 1.2-rc2 is /^\s*(https?|ftp|file):|data:image\//, to access the local filesystem for a chrome packaged app |filesystem:chrome-extension: should be added to the end of the regex.

Comment: My regex is this: `/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|skype):/` and it is applied at `aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` only.

Comment: Have you tried with (/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/) regex?

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work in following plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/rIPFz9WhFjlRJ1ogCArP?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', [])

.config(function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|skype|mailto|tel|file):/)
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.href = 'skype:123456?call';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it and it still add the `unsafe` prefix. In a normal Angular app I can get rid of it. In **meanjs** I don't know what to do to let it work.

Comment: using mean stack doesn't make much of a difference for Angular application. Most probably the `.config` runs in wrong place/not at all/on wrong module. Try to run getter`console.log($compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist())` after setting it up to see if the returned regex is updated

Comment: Yes, the regex is updated and it is applied in the core module as you can see. Even if the `aHrefSanitizationWhitelis‌​t` is updated it continue to prefix the `unsafe`.

Comment: Is `core` the module you bootstrap (is it in ng-app)? I see in question code you used self-invoked function, is it wrapping just config or everything else?

Comment: It wrap everything, the position where the code is applied is correct, I also tried to move it to the specific module configuration but nothing happen. It looks like something is forcing that state and I can not get rid of it. I searched for another `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` in the code and mine is the only one.

Comment: Which angular version exactly do you use? Do you include some extra libraries i.e. ngSanitize? did you set some sanitization rules?

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.5.8, and the meanjs package comes with ngSanitize, yes. I have not set any rules. Everything should be as default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142476/discussion-between-maurycy-and-ayeye-brazo).